# In Asana is there a way to associate completed tasks with a release version?

Tags: task-management, asana

I'm working mostly in [Asana](https://asana.com) right now, and am hoping to find a way to associate completed tasks with a versioned cut of product (software in this case).  Am I supposed to hack my workflow by creating a project for every release, then move some tasks from the long-list to each project version?

Comment: I don't use Asana, but why don't you just treat software releases as milestones and associate your tasks with the relevant milestones?

Answer (score 2):

The best way I've found to do this, given we migrated from JIRA to Asana, is to have a project for every release.  We also maintain two projects, one for new features/enhancements and another for bugs.  When planning a release we create the project with the release version and the product people and engineer leads then pick the tasks (stories) and move them into the release project.  Each task then is broken down with subtasks for the engineers to figure out how to implement.  The completed task will maintain the project it was created/completed in.  At the end of the release we archive the project.

Additional note, I also have the following release project created in advance for mid-release realignment to see if tasks aren't going to make it and need to spill over.

Answer (score 0):

No. Actually, Asana doesn't handle software releases or other software development related project steps. You'll either have to change to another service or build when you need with [Asana API](http://developer.asana.com).

**[Edit]**

If you are looking for something similar to Jira, you can use Jira together with Asana ([see here](https://asana.com/apps/jira)).

Comment: Jira is likely the tool I'm looking for.  Asana is just so much more pleasant to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the Project title + Task Name + link on the code commit/check-in

Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can associate completed tasks with a release version, if you pivot your definition for a completed task in Asana. My team will set up headers, such as "Staging" or "Production" and move completed tasks underneath those headers, Kanban style. You could also add release version headers, as well.

Once your team members move a task underneath the release header, I'd recommend they un-assign themselves and un-date the task.

The recently added "Project Overview" feature in Asana will be less accurate due to this change of not checking off tasks; however, in my team's experience, this feature is currently difficult to access for many project stakeholders and does not get much use anyways.